# Use create_list method many times in Rails FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two FactoryBots => `user` and `post`
And post has `user_id` column

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "user#{n}" }
  end
end
```

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "title#{n}" }
    sequence(:user_id) { |n| n }
  end
end
```

I want to make 10 users, and 100 posts (10posts per each user) so i
tried .times method like this =>

```
10.times do
  FactoryBot.define do
    factory :post do
      sequence(:title) { |n| "title#{n}" }
      sequence(:user_id) { |n| n }
    end
  end
end
```

This not worked because of `Factory already registered` error

```
  FactoryBot.define do
    10.times do
      factory :post do
        sequence(:title) { |n| "title#{n}" }
        sequence(:user_id) { |n| n }
      end
    end
  end
```

This not worked too.

```
FactoryBot.create_list(:user, 10)
10.times do
  FactoryBot.create_list(:post, 10)
end
```

This makes FactoryBot to make `post num 11, user num 11` so foriegn key error occurs.
How can i use create_list method many times?

Just i want to make is, 10 posts per 10 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to reference any of those users and/or posts afterward, then you can just 10 times create 10 posts using the same user per every 10 posts;

```
10.times do
  create_list(:post, 10, user: create(:user))
end
```